# Why cropped images color go deeper?

Tags: python, crop

I'm trying to test my model for some pathology images. And I need to crop them into small patches.
Here is my cropping code.

```
def crop_to_four_with_cropSize(image, crop_sz=None):
    if crop_sz == None:
        crop_sz = image.shape[0] // 2
    img_sz = image.shape[0]
    y = 0
    x = 0
    h = crop_sz
    w = crop_sz
    image_crop_1 = image[y:y + h, x:x + w, :]
    image_crop_2 = image[-h:, x:x + w, :]
    image_crop_3 = image[y:y + h, -w:, :]
    image_crop_4 = image[-h:, -w:, :]
    return (image_crop_1, image_crop_2, image_crop_3, image_crop_4)
```

And the following is the method I used for save.

```
def save_to_file(image, name, path='./'):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    full_name = os.path.join(path, name)
    scipy.misc.toimage(image).save(full_name)
```

[left is orignal image,right is cropped image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPYlN.png)

my model is color sensitive, but I have no idea why one number matrix has different degrees of brightness.

I'll appreciate your directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit here is the `scipy.misc.toimage` function. According to the warning in the [documentation of `toimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.toimage.html#scipy.misc.toimage), this function uses [`bytescale`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.bytescale.html#scipy.misc.bytescale) for scaling the array values to use the full range of a byte i.e. from 0 to 255. That is why the colors in the cropped image have better contrast.

If the `image` variable is an array-like object (`numpy` array etc.), then instead of using `scipy.misc.toimage` followed by `save`, you may use some other method to save the image to disk such as [`scipy.misc.imsave`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html#scipy-misc-imsave) of SciPy or [`imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce) function of OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks, my friend. scipy.misc.imsave doesn't work(the same condition in the question) but imwrite in OpenCV works well.